# Сохранение таблицы рекордов с libgdx на android

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр, libgdx

С десктопа сохранение и чтение работает, а когда запускаю на телефоне, ничего не работает.
Вот код:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;

public class ScoreManager {

    private int score;

    public void getScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    private File f = new File("highscore.txt");

    public int s;

    public boolean isHigh(int score) {
        return score > s;
    }

    public void SaveScore() {
        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(f.getAbsoluteFile());
            out.print(score);
            out.close();
        } 
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();            
        }
    }

    public void LoadScore() {
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(f.getAbsoluteFile());
            while(sc.hasNext())
                s = sc.nextInt();
            sc.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Gdx.app.exit();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @rishat, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @rishat, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, нужно указать директорию для файла. Например, так:

```
    String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getPath() + "/highscore.txt"
   f = new File(dir);
```

И не забудьте про пермишен в манифесте:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

[Вот статья на всякий случай](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/138-urok-75-hranenie-dannyh-rabota-s-fajlami).

Comment: Почему-то подчеркивает DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS

Comment: @rishat подчёркивает И чтото пишет. что пишет?

Comment: можно просто Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() писать
пареметры типо DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS нужны, если файл нужно в общую директорию записать типо музыка, фото, документы и прочее

Comment: Пишет вот это:

>The method getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() is undefined for the type Environment

Comment: @argamidon тоже фигню какую-то:

>DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: @rishat, а вы уверены, что импортировали Environment?(тот, что нужно, может их несколько у вас?)

Answer (score 2):

В libgdx есть специальный класс для хранения конфигурации приложения:

```
Preferences pref = Gdx.app.getPreferences("MyPreference");
```

можете воспользоваться им

Comment: И по-моему это в разы удобней.